# SQL SELECT, GROUP BY

Tags: sql

Why do I have to group all my selected columns in group by if i started to group by one column?

For instance, why can't i just have only two groups? as below:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D
FROM MYTB
GROUB BY A, B
```

Comment: Only mysql lets you get away with indeterminate values.

Comment: What you are aggregating will determine what has to be included in the GROUP BY. In your example you aren't aggregating anything.

Comment: IN sql server you can use aggregates with window functions something like SUM(A) OVER (PARTITION BY...)

Comment: If there are multiple rows for a given `A` and `B`, which values for `C` and `D` would you choose?  Which should the database engine choose?

Comment: Your query is ambiguous.  Are you just trying to sort?  Then use `ORDER BY`.  Are you trying to use an aggregate function like `SUM()`?  Then use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I see now that, I should use Order by with no aggregates and group by when i do have aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by as many elements as you want. Just make sure any non-grouped elements in your select have some aggregation.

```
SELECT A, B, SUM(C), MAX(D)
FROM MYTB
GROUP BY A, B
```

See

- Basic info: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php
- Grouping by more than 1 column: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby_2